# Change biblatex citation style

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am struggling to find the right settings of biblatex for my use case. Given the following entry in the .bib file

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
}
```

I would like to have the following Output for `\footcite[Vgl.][12--15]{einstein}`

```
Vgl. Einstein (1905), S. 12 ff.
```

and an corresponding entry in the bibliography as follows

```
Einstein, A. (1905): Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper, in: Annalen der Physik, Jg. 322 (10), S. 891-921.
```

I tried using authoryear as style and authoryear-ibid as citestyle (ibid is necessary) and they come close but I have to follow really strict specifications, so I need to change these styles. Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea where to start as this is my first time using biblatex. 
I looked for a solution in other threads but they all seem to be really specific to the respective problem so I can't seem to find a "general way" to change citation styles.

If anyone could tell me if there is an easy solution or point me to a tutorial where I can learn how to write or change styles that would be great!

Edit:
Minimal working sample:
sample.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample.bib} 

\begin{document}

Random sentence.\footcite[Vgl.][12--15]{einstein}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

sample.bib:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you add a minimal latex file showing what options you currently pass to biblatex.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{advertisement}
```

For small tweaks like this the styles of my [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) bundle can be more convenient than the standard styles.

In particular the punctuation macros `\jourvoldelim` and `\volnumdelim` allow us to avoid having to redefine the two bibmacros `journal+issuetitle` and `volume+number+eid`.

`\DeclareInnerCiteDelims` gives us a quick way to wrap the year in the footnote citation into round brackets, something that would otherwise require redefining the `cite` or `cite:labeldate+extradate` bibmacros, which could clash with `\textcite` if done incorrectly.

Everything else in the code below is standard `biblatex`.

```
\end{advertisement}
```

The comments explain what each code block does, more can be found in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

% comma between bibliography units
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% colon after Author (Year) in bibliography
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% no quotation marks around titles
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

% Journal, Jg. Vol (Num)
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addnbspace}

% parentheses around year in footcite
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Random sentence.\autocite[Vgl.][380\psqq]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The footnote reads "Vgl. Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998), S. 380 ff.", the bibliography entry "Sigfridsson, E. und U. Ryde (1998): Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments, in: Journal of Computational Chemistry, Jg. 19 (4), S. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P."]

As [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann) mentions [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925) is a great starting point for common and easy modifications, but you can find many more complicated customisations on this site if you search for specific terms. A few of the `biblatex` tutorials listed in [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864) have a short "common customisation" section or mention a few common modifications. Other than that you can find out what macro to modify and which field format to tweak by looking at the source of your style (`biblatex.def`, `biblatex.bbx` and `<bibstyle>.bbx`, `<citestyle>.cbx`).

Comment: That's really great. I will have a look at those links. Thank you!